# .NET 4.5 Async/Await and the Garbage Collector

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, async-await

I am wondering about the behavior of `async/await` in relation to garbage collecting local variables. In the following example, I have allocated a sizable portion of memory and go into a significant delay. As seen in the code, `Buffer` is not used after the `await`. Will it get garbage collected while waiting, or will the memory be occupied for the duration of the function?

```
/// <summary>
/// How does async/await behave in relation to managed memory?
/// </summary>
public async Task<bool> AllocateMemoryAndWaitForAWhile() {
    // Allocate a sizable amount of memory.
    var Buffer = new byte[32 * 1024 * 1024];
    // Show the length of the buffer (to avoid optimization removal).
    System.Console.WriteLine(Buffer.Length);
    // Await one minute for no apparent reason.
    await Task.Delay(60000);
    // Did 'Buffer' get freed by the garabage collector while waiting?
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It depends on how the compiler translates this. async-await is not a CLR concept. (Still, it is a valid question).

Comment: Nice example how the incorrect answer receives most upvotes.

Comment: @Soonts: I am somewhat amused that you think my answer is incorrect. I assure you it is a correct statement of what *guarantees* are made by the C# language. Anything else is an implementation detail subject to change at any time.

Comment: @EricLippert, the OP's question is not theoretical. He’s not asking “what is guaranteed by the C# language”. He rather asked “how it works”. Of course, the implementation details might change with the next visual studio or even a service pack. In that case, the correct answer will change from “no” to “yes”. Before this happened however, in the current production version of the visual studio 2012, the correct answer is not “maybe”, but “no”.

Comment: @soonts async void m(){ var x = new X(); await n(x.h); } h is a handle, ~X() deallocates it. I ask you if the destructor can run before the task completes. If it does then the process corrupts a database. Is your answer still that this is perfectly safe because the finalizer cannot run? now do you see why it is important to consider what is guaranteed and what just happens to work? Use good engineering practices, don't rely on implementation details.

Comment: @EricLippert, using finalizers for such things is never a “good engineering practice”. The correct solution for such problems would be implementing IDisposable interface, then write using(var x = new X()){await n(x.h);}. Besides, your example is unrelated to the OP’s question. He was clearly concerned about RAM usage, not about the things you’re trying to drag in.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Will it get garbage collected while waiting?

Maybe. The garbage collector is permitted to do so but not required to.

> Will the memory be occupied for the duration of the function?

Maybe. The garbage collector is permitted to do so but not required to.

Basically, if the garbage collector can know that the buffer will never be touched again then it can free it at any time. But the GC is never *required* to free anything on any particular schedule.

If you are particularly concerned, you can always set the local to `null`, but I would not bother doing so unless you demonstrably had a problem. Alternatively, you could extract the code that manipulates the buffer into its own non-async method and call it synchronously from the async method; then the local becomes just an ordinary local of an ordinary method.

> The `await` is realized as a `return`, so the local will go out of scope and its lifetime will be over; the array will then be collected on the next collection, which is required to be during the `Delay`, right?

No, none of those claims are true.

First, an `await` is only a `return` if the task is not completed; now, it is of course nigh impossible that `Delay` will be completed, so yes, this will return, but we cannot conclude in general that an `await` returns to the caller.

Second, the local only vanishes if it is actually realized in IL by the C# compiler as local in the temporary pool. The jitter will jit that as a stack slot or register, which vanishes when the activation for the method ends at the `await`. But the C# compiler is not required to do that!

It would seem strange to a person in the debugger to put a breakpoint after the `Delay` and see that the local has vanished, so the compiler *might* realize the local as a field in a compiler-generated class that is bound to the lifetime of the class generated for the state machine. In that case it is much less likely that the jitter will realize that this field is never read again, and therefore much less likely to throw it away early. (Though it is *permitted* to do so. And also the C# compiler is *permitted* to set the field to null on your behalf if it can prove that you're done using it. Again, this would be weird for the person in the debugger who suddenly sees their local change value for no apparant reason, but the compiler is permitted to generate *any* code whose single-threaded behaviour is correct.)

Third, nothing requires the garbage collector to collect anything on any particular schedule. This large array will be allocated on the large object heap, and that thing has its own collection schedule.

Fourth, nothing whatsoever requires there to be a collection of the large object heap in any given sixty second interval. That thing need never be collected if there is no memory pressure.

Comment: *No* turned to *maybe*, yes or no? or what is the rule?

Comment: @IV4: I misread the code the first time but quickly realized my mistake.

Comment: `if the garbage collector can know that the buffer will never be touched again then it can free it at any time` Does GC know it at `await Task.Delay(60000);` ?

Comment: "lifetime of the delegate generated for the state machine" - the async state machine is not a delegate, it a structure implementing the IAsyncStateMachine interface.

Comment: @Soonts: You are of course correct. When we were designing the feature it was going to be a delegate, but by the time it was released there was an interface. Not that it particularly matters for the purposes of this question what the exact shape of the compiler-generated class is.

Comment: @EricLippert it matters a lot. Inside delegates, local variables are still local variables. In the class/structure, the local variables of the async method are no longer "local", they become fields instead.

Comment: @Soonts: Not necessarily. A local like the one mentioned here does not *have* to become a field; it could remain a local because it does not have to survive across an `await`. You're confusing two things that have nothing to do with each other: (1) whether locals that need not survive across an `await` are generated as field of the closure or locals of `MoveNext`, and (2) what part of the code turns the `MoveNext` method into a delegate. Those two design choices are *orthogonal*.

Comment: @EricLippert, first of all, I’m not saying MS should implement async/await with delegates: I’m happy with the current implementation, and I know why they did that. However, the design choices are not orthogonal: delegates only capture the variables they use, while classes/structures retain every single field/property.

Comment: @soonts I'm not sure how I can say this more clearly. The choice of what to reify as a field has nothing to do with whether the method is turned into a delegate or not. A variable which must survive an await must be a field, regardless of whether movenext is converted to a delegate or not. The decision to reify other variables is independent of the decision to use delegatesor not.

Comment: @EricLippert, it depends. If the implementation would e.g. split an async method into multiple nested delegate — then a variable, which must survive an await, might be just a local variable declared in the first delegate, and referenced in the second. Without any fields.

Answer (score 7):

What Eric Lippert said is true: the C# compiler has quite a lot of leeway about what IL should it generate for the `async` method. So, if you're asking what does the specification say about this, then the answer is: the array **may** be eligible for collection during the wait, which means it may be collected.

But another question is what the compiler actually does. On my computer, the compiler generates `Buffer` as a field of generated state machine type. That field is set to the allocated array, and then it's never set again. That means the array will become eligible for collection when the state machine object does. And that object is referenced from the continuation delegate, so it won't become eligible for collection until after the wait completes. What this all means is that the array **won't** be eligible for collection during the wait, which means it won't be collected.

Some more notes:

1. The state machine object is actually a `struct`, but it's used though an interface it implements, so it behaves as a reference type for the purpose of garbage collection.
2. If you actually determine that the fact that the array won't be collected is a problem for you, it might be worth to set the local to `null` before the `await`. But in the vast majority of cases, you don't have to worry about this. I'm certainly not saying you should regularly set locals to `null` before `await`.
3. This is very much an implementation detail. It can change at any time and different versions of the compiler may behave differently.

Comment: Good points all. I would add that there was some talk during the design phase to detect these situations at compile time and automatically null out the fields, so as to make life easier on the garbage collector (and harder on the developer looking at the locals in the debugger that mysteriously turned to null.) I do not know what was decided.

Answer (score 3):

Your code compiles (in my environment: VS2012, C# 5, .NET 4.5, Release mode) to include a struct that implements `IAsyncStateMachine`, and has the following field:

```
public byte[] <Buffer>5__1;
```

Thus, unless the JIT and/or GC are *really* clever, (see [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598680/781792) for more on that) it'd be reasonable to assume that the large `byte[]` will stay in scope until the async task is complete.

Comment: I think this doesn't really answer the question, you also need to know: 1. Doesn't the compiler set the field to `null`? 2. When will the state machine struct (it's actually not a class) become eligible for collection?

Comment: @svik, (1) no it doesn't, compile and use Reflector to verify (2) After the completion of the async method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure its collected, since await ends your current task and "continues with" another task,
so local vars should be cleaned when they are not used after the await.

BUT: What the compiler actually does could be something different, so I would not depend on such a behaviour.

Comment: I've addressed your supposition in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an update on this topic with Rolsyn compiler.

Running following code in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 in release configuration produces

```
True
False
```

So the locals are garbage collected.

```
    private static async Task MethodAsync()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        var wr = new WeakReference(bytes);

        Console.WriteLine(wr.Target != null);

        await Task.Delay(100);

        FullGC();

        Console.WriteLine(wr.Target != null);

        await Task.Delay(100);

    }

    private static void FullGC()
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Note, that if we modify MethodAsync to use local variable after await, then array buffer will not be garbage collected.

```
 private static async Task MethodAsync()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        var wr = new WeakReference(bytes);

        Console.WriteLine(wr.Target != null);

        await Task.Delay(100);

        Console.WriteLine(bytes.Length);

        FullGC();

        Console.WriteLine(wr.Target != null);

        await Task.Delay(100);

        FullGC();

        Console.WriteLine(wr.Target != null);
    }
```

The output for this is

```
True
1024
True
True
```

The code samples are taken from this rolsyn [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/437).

Answer (score -2):

> Will it get garbage collected while waiting?

Nope.

> will the memory be occupied for the duration of the function?

Yes.

Open your compiled assembly in Reflector. You'll see the compiler generated a private struct that inherits from IAsyncStateMachine, the local variables of your async method being a field of that struct. The data fields of the class/struct are never freed while the owning instance is still alive.

Comment: Well, that just replaces one question with another: when will the owning instance stop being alive?

Comment: After the completion of the method. Before that, the task scheduler holds the reference to call MoveNext method after the timeout. If you want to cancel earlier, pass a CancelationTocken to the Task.Delay.